# How to integrate $x e^{-|x|}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I calculate $\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{1}{2}xce^{-c|x|}dx$? I know that the answer is $0$, but how do I show this? With integration by parts?

Comment: You have an *odd* function.

Comment: You have an *odd* and *integrable* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate it into two parts
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{2}xce^{-c|x|}dx &= \int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{2}xce^{cx}dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2}xce^{-cx}dx \\
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2}xce^{-cx}dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2}xce^{-cx}dx\\
&=0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: A technicality: for this to be valid one must also show that the integrals are convergent (which is not very difficult in this case, but still).